# Confused about rxjs operator imports

Tags: typescript, import, rxjs, rxjs5

I have updated the imports for rxjs operators in my project so that they now conform to the new recommended syntax, such as:

```
import { switchMap, debounceTime }          from 'rxjs/operators';
```

However when I try to follow the same pattern for the "***do***" operator, TypeScript complains when I build my code.  In order to get it to work, I need to use the older syntax pattern such as:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
```

Am I doing something wrong or is the older pattern still needed for the "***do***" operator?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you update rxjs or just the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `do` operator was renamed in RxJS 5.5 to `tap` (because `do` is a reserved keyword):

```
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

For more info see section "Renamed Operators" in https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md#pipeable-operators